# phpunit setup in Docker Container

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, phpunit

I have following docker-compose.yml file for PHP Docker application. I tried to setup PHPUnit in this docker container. But It is showing following error

`Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./vendor/bin/phpunit": stat ./vendor/bin/phpunit: no such file or directory: unknown`

docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  composer:
    image: composer:2
    environment:
      - COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR=/app/var/cache/composer
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    restart: always
  sql-db:
    build:
      context: ./sql-db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: codingchallenge
      MYSQL_DATABASE: codingchallenge
      MYSQL_USER: codingchallenge
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: codingchallenge
    ports:
      - "8322:3306"
    networks:
      - backend-php
  php-fpm:
    depends_on:
      - sql-db
      - nginx_backend
    build: ./php-fpm
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DB_HOST: sql-db
      MYSQL_DB_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_DB_USER: codingchallenge
      MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD: codingchallenge
      MYSQL_DATABASE: codingchallenge
      DATABASE_URL: mysql://codingchallenge:codingchallenge@sql-db:3306/codingchallenge
    networks:
      - backend-php
    volumes:
      - sock:/sock
      - ./app:/var/www
      - ./vendor:/var/www/vendor
    links:
      - sql-db
  nginx_backend:
    build:
      context: ./nginx-backend
    ports:
      - "8321:80"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www:ro
      - sock:/sock
    networks:
      - backend-php
    restart: always
  phpunit:
      image: php:7.3-cli
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - sock:/sock
        - ./app:/var/www
        - ./vendor:/var/www/vendor
      working_dir: /app
      entrypoint: vendor/bin/phpunit
volumes:
  sock:

networks:
  backend-php:
```

If any one know how to setup PHPUnit in above container.

I added PHPUnit container in the docker-compose.yml file. But still not working and throwing vendor/bin/phpunit not found error.

Answer (score 0):

PHPUnit is not a service and shouldn't be declared as such. Otherwise it would be constantly running in an infinite loop.

You can run it issuing an `exec` command to the `php-fpm` service.

Also the problem is that your directory names don't match. Remove `vendor` volume altogether. Working directory should be `/var/www`.

Composer also shouldn't be a separate service. It doesn't serve anything, it's called on demand. Include it into the `php-fpm` service using `COPY --from`. It would simplify many use cases, e.g. checking platform dependencies.